Joining across multiple CTE
I m trying to create a table that shows the the number of unique user(Sessions) on every page of the website, grouped by marketing channel, then grouped click events, count of the clicks event and download that are have been attributed to those groups.
I am not exactly sure how to best explain this but that table will be used to calculate the conversion rate at row level for each groups.
see below

My question is about the best approach as much as the answer.
The first CTE SESSIONS was created to collect all the USER_ID that match the criteria for subsetting, then with the intention of join back on it with the other CTE however I have noticed I m not getting the rights counts, at least not how I need them.
Is this the right approach or is there something better to do?
WITH SESSIONS AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT(EVENTS.USER_ID) 
    FROM PAGE
        INNER JOIN VISITS
            ON PAGE.USER_ID = VISITS.USER_ID
        INNER JOIN MARKETING
            ON PAGE.USER_ID = MARKETING.USER_ID
        INNER JOIN EVENTS
            ON PAGE.USER_ID = EVENTS.USER_ID
    WHERE 1=1
        AND PAGE.URL='www.url.com'
    ),
EVENT AS(
    SELECT EVENTS.URL,EVENTS.USER_ID,EVENTS.EA,EVENTS.EL 
    FROM EVENTS
    WHERE  EVENTS.EA = 'Next Page Click' 
    AND EVENTS.URL='www.url.com'
    GROUP BY EVENTS.URL,EVENTS.USER_ID,EVENTS.EA,EVENTS.EL 
    ),
CONV AS(
    SELECT EVENTS.USER_ID, 
        CASE WHEN EVENTS.EA = 'Download' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS Download
    FROM EVENTS
    WHERE  EVENTS.EA = 'Download' 
    GROUP BY EVENTS.USER_ID,EVENTS.EA
    ),
MKTING AS(
    SELECT MARKETING.USER_ID, MARKETING.CHANNEL
    FROM MARKETING
    )
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT(SE.USER_ID)) Sessions,
        PAGE.URL,MKTING.CHANNEL,EVENT.EA,EVENT.EL,
        SUM(CONV.Download) AS Download
FROM SESSIONS AS SE
    LEFT JOIN EVENT
                ON SE.USER_ID = EVENT.USER_ID   
    LEFT JOIN CONV
        ON EVENT.USER_ID = CONV.USER_ID 
    LEFT JOIN MKTING
        ON SE.USER_ID = MKTING.USER_ID 
GROUP BY PAGE.URL,MKTING.CHANNEL,EVENT.EA,EVENT.EL
ORDER BY Sessions DESC;


Would help if you add the expected result to better understand the problem.

The screenshot of the table is the expected results. Sorry of that isn't clear
